# Getting total number of rows using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in Zend DB Table Select

Tags: php, sql, mysql, zend-framework

Is there a way to get the total number of rows in Zend db select like with using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in a regular mysql query. I haven't been able to find a similar functionality for this apart from running the same query without the limit clause.

Answer (score 11):

```
$db->select()
   ->from($tableName, array(
       new Zend_Db_Expr('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id'), 
       'name', 
       'price'
   ));
```

You could also try **replacing all cols with COUNT(*)** and running the query second time. It may actually be more efficient (even if it's *counter-intuitive*). This was the case for my app.

You can do it like this:

```
$select->reset('cols')->reset('limit')->cols('COUNT(*)'); //there is a constant for the 'cols' in Select class
$db->query($select);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because no one else has anything better to offer I'll suggest to see [this post](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Adding-SELECT-options-to-Zend-Db-Select-tp673667p673672.html) on a ZF forum. It's from 2008 and ZF may have been upgraded since then.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method if data inside the rows also needed

```
   $rows = $db->select()->from('foo')->query()->fetchAll(); 

    echo 'Total number of rows found : ' . count($rows);
```

if you just need the count of total number of rows then

```
$count = $db->select()->from('foo','COUNT(*)')->query()->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Although it works this is very inefficient especially if you are using MySQL. Using the calc_rows saves retrieval of alot data to find out how many entries there are without any limit for paging. To make it database independend you could also implement a seperate COUNT query.

Comment: efficient way added I though that number of total rows were needed